# How to show days of week in checkbox in ReactJs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to show the day of the week(which comes from JSON) in a select box with others. However, it shows only the current day which come from JSON instead of other days of the week. The first map(schedule) is what comes from the server and the second map which I use to show days of the week. I added picture at the end. How can I solve it?

```
    
    const options = [
      {
        label: "Mon",
        value: "Mon"
      }, {
        label: "Tue",
        value: "Tue"
      }, {
        label: "Wed",
        value: "Wed"
      }, {
        label: "Thu",
        value: "Thu"
      }, {
        label: "Fri",
        value: "Fri"
      }, {
        label: "Sat",
        value: "Sat"
      }
    ];
```

```
<Col className="align-content-start date">
  <h5>
    <b>Days of Week</b>
    <div className="select-container">
      {e.schedules.map((sc, id) => {
        return (
          <>
            {' '}
            <select>
              {options.map(option => {
                return (
                  <>
                    {' '}
                    <option value={option}>{sc.Day}</option>{' '}
                  </>
                );
              })}
            </select>{' '}
            <h5> {sc.Hour} </h5>{' '}
          </>
        );
      })}
    </div>
  </h5>
</Col>
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/qAv72.png

Answer (score 1):

Change `sc.Day` to `option.label`

```html
<option value={option}>{option.label}</option>
```

Comment: Yes like that it shows all days. but I want to keep the current day as it is which comes from server. I want to show sc.Day as an initial day in a selection box

Answer (score 1):

You were actually pretty close, but you need to add the object properties to your `select` elements. If you want the day coming from the server to be the selected value, you can set the `value` prop on the `select` element to that day.

```js
function App() {
  const sc = { Day: 'Wed' };
  const options = [
    {
      label: 'Mon',
      value: 'Mon',
    },
    {
      label: 'Tue',
      value: 'Tue',
    },
    {
      label: 'Wed',
      value: 'Wed',
    },
    {
      label: 'Thu',
      value: 'Thu',
    },
    {
      label: 'Fri',
      value: 'Fri',
    },
    {
      label: 'Sat',
      value: 'Sat',
    },
  ];

  return (
    <select value={sc.Day}>
      {options.map((option) => {
        return (
          <option key={option.value} value={option.value}>
            {option.label}
          </option>
        );
      })}
    </select>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector('#root'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

And don't forget to add a unique `key` prop if you iterate over elements.

Comment: Yes, but my problem is to keep sc.Day as current day of week.

Comment: Should that be the selected option? I've just updated my answer.

Comment: yes it should be selected option. My goal is: I get day of week from server, but later if I want I can choose from select option and modify this day

Comment: I've just added a snippet. If the `sc.Day` is Wed, it's the selected day by default. You can run the snippet above to check it.